# Mouse movement for beginners

Tags: windows, mouse

On Windows 3.11 has a nice tutorial for beginners using mouse. Since then I consider that tutor the best of all tutorial to learn mouse movement, clicks, double-clicks, etc.

Do you know some nice tutorial (app) to beginners using mouse? I need it to teach a lot of people that purchase PCs with me...

My preferences are:

1) Multilingual OR low use of native languages, so the app can be universal;
2) A minimal possible of dependencies

Thank you for all!

Comment: you'd think that MS wouldn't mind giving away a 17 year old OS that they discontinued support for 9 years ago. if you are dead set on getting that application (which probably wouldn't run on a modern Windows OS) your best bet may be to check eBay for a copy of windows 3.1x and run it in a VM as you mentioned in another comment

Comment: Man, Windows 3.11 had good tutorials for EVERYTHING.  I forget what it was called but there were walkthrough style tutorials for pretty much every single system utility..it's really how I learned to use a computer.  They need to bring that stuff back!

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of basic Mouse tutorials out there.
A simple google search brought these up on the first page:

http://www.basics4beginners.com/site/MouseTutorial.aspx

http://www.mesalibrary.org/research/mouse/page01.htm

http://www.seniornet.org/howto/mouseexercises/mousepractice.html

Hope some of these help.

I also agree with Alan, a lot of the Windows 3.1 tutorial could confuse current users as it bears no resembelence to the screens they look at.

Comment: Nice, but scrolling and another features I call "advanced" mouse movements. That tutors are good, but not so simple as the win 3.11 tutor... :/

Answer (score 2):

It's [on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJhG-uds0-o), I don't know how relevant it will be with today's user interfaces, scroll mice and the like.

Comment: Yes, is it! But I need the app! I thought in VMWare, but I think a elephant to kill an ant!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any modern app that does it,but, for mouse movements..I want to give you an hint: I remember someone told me one time the games contained in Windows are been created to help the user to understand the use of the mouse.
Take as example solitarie.
It teaches you drag and drop and the single click.
To teach double click, control panel, mouse, section where you regulate the timing, there is a reactive box where you train the double click.

Teaching how to use a mouse can take max 4 hours, then you have to let the user practise for itself.

How to teach scrolling: finger on the wheel, and rotate it a little down, a little more there, here you go, now you know how scroll down. If you want to go up, do the opposite.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Show the user Solitaire, and how to set it to single card.
Then let them play it, until mouse motions become automatic.
That is a very good first step.

Herman